# Como paginar uma consulta no Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-azure, nosql, cosmos-db

Estou tentando paginar uma consulta no `Azure Cosmos DB`, lendo esse post: [*Paging through query results in Azure DocumentDB*](https://www.kevinkuszyk.com/2016/08/19/paging-through-query-results-in-azure-documentdb/), cheguei ao código:

```
    public async Task <ICollection <TEntity>> GetAllPaged(int page, string colletionId) {
     FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions {
      MaxItemCount = 10
     };

     var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery <TEntity> (
       UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, colletionId), queryOptions)
      .AsDocumentQuery();

     FeedResponse <TEntity> result;
     List <TEntity> tEntitys = new List <TEntity> ();
     int interacoes = 0;
     while (query.HasMoreResults) {
      interacoes++;
      if (interacoes == page) {
       result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync <TEntity> ();
       tEntitys = result.ToList();
       break;
      }

     }
     return tEntitys;

    }
```

## Explicando:

- `MaxItemCount = 10`, total de itens por página.
- `while (query.HasMoreResults)`, execute um `loop` até que haja resultados.
- `if (interacoes == page)`, quando chegar na minha página não preciso mais verificar os próximos, onde entra o `break`.

## Problema:

Imaginem que tenho cerca de 50002 documentos, e que minha página solicite ao método o resultado de número 5001, ou seja, os 2 últimos registros.

A cada interação do `while` esse código:`result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<TEntity>()` é responsável por cada página de resultados.

Pensei em executar esse código somente na página especifica que necessito através desse código :`if (interacoes == page)`, o problema disso é que somente o primeiro resultado é lido, ou seja, eu preciso ler página por página para conseguir o resultado desejado descrito no cenário acima, e isso tem me gerado 15 segundos de performasse.

***Nota:*** `Skip` não é suportado pois oferece uma péssima performasse. Mais nos [Issues do GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/issues/377)!

## O que posso fazer para melhorar isso?

Comment: A pergunta é de astronomia? :P :D

Comment: @Maniero dá uma força ai :) rs!

Comment: Não manjo disso :)

Answer (score 2):

Olá, talvez essa biblioteca posso te ajudar [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut). Ela é específica para o Cosmos DB e facilita muito as queries, o que você precisa está na seguinte implementação.

```
.WithPagination(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
```

É uma extensão do IQueryable. no próprio github do [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) você via encontrar diversos exemplos de utilização.